# Can I reduce the thickness of any traced object without losing dimensions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This circle is a traced object. I want to make it half thinner but I don't want to lose the dimensions. Also there is fill color and no stroke, how can I make it thinner?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess with *outlined* you mean traced, if this is the case:

- Make a ring (red in the image), a single circle width a white stroke as thick as the desired width, centered to the original image
- Apply a smooth **Roughen Effect** to this ring

[image: ring]

- Add a 100% black square frame and send it back
- Select both shapes and got to **Menu Edit** > **Cut**

[image: Mask]

- Select the original shape, and from the **Transparency Panel** click **Make Mask**
- Uncheck **Clip**
- Click the right square at the **Transparency Panel** to activate the mask area
- Paste in front : <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win

[image: Mask]

- Click the left square at the **Transparency Panel** to activate the editing area

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Animation**

[image: animation]

Comment: You are awesome please help me in few steps

step 1 
did you created circle with ellipse tool and give it stroke without fill?

step 2
i added square shape but what do you mean by cut both shapes?

Comment: Answer updated with the solutions

Comment: i am new here on this forum. is there any private message system?

Comment: i am confused sorry to say i am still not able to solve it

Comment: Answer updated with an animation .gif